# Help changing the Under Construction Visualforce Page for a Community's Force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, community

Situation is as follows... we have a Salesforce community located at say `lumberco.force.com/trees` so whenever a user accesses an invalid URL... say `lumberco.force.com/tree` they receive the Standard Under Construction page for the site.

Which is expected behavior, except for the fact that it displays

> lumberco.force.com/trees/ is under construction
>   Stay tuned. Please [email us](http://mailto:myboss@lumberco.co) if you need to get in touch.

so the user never realizes they entered a bad URL, and chooses the email link.  This email (by default) is pulled from the `Site Contact` which must be a user record.  But we have a shared email: `treeguru@lumberco.co` which is essentially a distribution list that needs to be there instead.

So I created a copy of the Standard Under Construction VF page, and hardcoded the distribution list address in the email hyperlink.  The problem is, that I can't find the binding between the Force.com site for my community and the VF page Salesforce is using when an incorrect URL is entered.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get that email changed?

Answer (score 1):

Look Under Customize->Communities->Manage Communities. Then Click the Custom Pages link which will take you to the list of Visualforce pages enabled for community which are under Site Visualforce pages. Then uou can change the email in the default Under Construction page.

Comment: Right, but I do not want to change the default Under Construction page, as that would affect my other Force.com sites.  I need a way to specify for the community which VF page to use.

Comment: you could use a custom controller with Under Construction page and change the email for that specific community.

Comment: Okay, so I followed the suggested path to the Under Construction VF page, and used some conditionals in the VF page rather than create an apex controller. It should have worked. It did not. I even removed 99% of the VF code and the displayed under construction page **remained completely unaffected**, so by all appearances I still need to find a way to specify which VF page the community should use.